# can any one suggest me which project can be best for half known student of vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i am student of t y bsc...
i have my 1.5 month project 
can any one suggest me any topics that can be also make some sort of money and easy to make a  project
I want to used Vb.net and sql server ...............V S 2010 and sql  server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make project for library management system which every student make in its college time and this project also having difficult task(at student label) and try to implement each and ever task of library. try to implement barcode reader for books. Implemeting Bar code reader is not expensive.

Some other topic may be,

Work monitoring system,Hospital management,college management etc.

Comment: Good suggestions. Try adding more detail as to how he may start +1